# change a phone number as a string into all numbers

Tags: java

[image]Im writing a program in java that is suppose to receive a phone number as a string, (ex. 1800helpmee) from the user and print out its corresponding numbers. 1800 435 7633 should be the answer. this is the code i have so far. I've loaded the number into the array. I am having an issue with the next part. my array is called inputNumber. I tried something like this but it doesn't seem to be working

```
for (int j = 0;  j<9; j ++) { 
        if ( inputNumber[j] =='A' || inputNumber[j] == 'B' || inputNumber[j] =='C'){
            System.out.println("2");
        }  etc.
```

Comment: By what rule did you conclude that `1800helpmee` should translate into `1800 435 7633`?

Comment: on the keypad of a phone thats what those letters convert to

Comment: and yes it can be either upper or lower case but I'm trying to solve one problem at a time lol

Comment: 'I am having an issue' which exact issue do you have? Does your code work? Please, share more details description.

Comment: this website won't let me upload a photo because i don't have 10 points or something. my code gets to the point where i have the array loaded with the number from the user. the if statement i posted above was my attempt at going through the array one by one and changing the letters to the appropriate numbers

Comment: however it doesn't work because it says incomparable types char and string..... I'm just stuck at a what to do here.

Comment: post the code for `inputNumber[]`. Of what type is it?

Comment: its a stringScanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        char letter;
        String [] inputNumber = new String [9];
        System.out.println("Please enter a phone number as a combination of numbers and letters");
        for (int i = 0; i<9; i++)
        { inputNumber[i] = input.next();
        }

Comment: this is the beginning of my code where i get the number and it goes into an array call inputNumber   ... sorry for the format i can't figure this website out

Answer (score 1):

switch `inputNumber[j] =='A'` to `inputNumber[j].equalsIgnoreCase("a")` apply this for a, b and c then retry

Comment: i switched the code to what you said and the error went away but the program isn't working at all? i posted the full code.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a for each loop to iterate the strings array

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String [] inputNumber = {"1","8","0","0","h","e","l","p"}; 

    for (String number : inputNumber) {
        switch (number.toUpperCase()) {
            case "A":
            case "B":
            case "C":
                System.out.println("2");
                break;
            case "D":
            case "E":
            case "F":
                System.out.println("3");
                break;
            // other letters
            default:
                System.out.println(number);
        }
    }
}
```

Evaluate each letter with a switch (as of Java 7) and print the aproppriate number. Notice the *fall through*, a break statement after several `case`. The toUpper() method is called to compare only with the uppercase version of each letter.

Comment: how can i use that but still go through each character in the string array?

Comment: Do you mean use a traditional for loop? You're in fact going through each character with the for each loop.

Comment: oh i see what your saying. what you wrote does go through each letter in the array. however the code still doesn't return anything?

Comment: It prints the number replacing the characters with the actual number.